# How do I exit a Price Check Loop once desired or lower price is met and commit to purchase?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to to automate an amazon purchase when the right set price hits in the code compared to to current amazon price.

It seems that it just goes into infinite loop rather than refresh the page and execute once the set price or lower hits. Is there an easier way to code it?

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
import chromedriver_binary
import random
import time

wd = wd.Chrome()
wd.implicitly_wait(10)

wd.get("https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0951JZDWT/ref=olp-opf-redir?aod=1&ie=UTF8&condition=ALL")

random_wait_time = random.randrange(2.0, 7.0)
print(random_wait_time)
time.sleep(random_wait_time)

price_id = "aod-price-1"
# find top price on page

current_price = wd.find_element_by_id(price_id).text

print(current_price)

disallowed_characters = "$\n"

for character in disallowed_characters:
    current_price = current_price.replace(character, "")

print(current_price)

amazon_price = int(current_price)

buy_price = int(5500)
# limit price to purchase item

while (amazon_price) >= int(buy_price):
    print(amazon_price)
    print('do not buy')
    random_wait_time = random.randrange(8.0, 20.0)
    print(random_wait_time)
    time.sleep(random_wait_time)
    wd.refresh()
else:
    add_to_cart_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-autoid-2-offer-1"]/span/input')
    add_to_cart_button.click()

view_cart_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="aod-offer-view-cart-1"]/span/input')

view_cart_button.click()
```

Comment: The amazon_price never changes. You don't ever update it. You refresh the page but don't pull the new price from it. So the while loop will loop forever because nothing changes.

Comment: Thank you. I put another loop inside it and it does exit out of the loop when the price gets updated after the browser refresh.

Comment: I'm not sure if it needed more loops, just to actually check the price, but I'm glad I could help.